# Kubernetes CentOS 8 tc command missing impact

Tags: kubernetes, centos8

While configuring Kubernetes 1.17 in CentOS 8, kubeadm gave the warning saying `tc` command not in the path.

tc command has been removed in CentOS 8, what is the impact for Kubernetes not having this command on the host?

```
  tc - show / manipulate traffic control settings
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `tc` command doesn't delete in CentOS8.
In CentOS8, Seem like only delete `-ok` option in `tc` command.
https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html-single/considerations_in_adopting_rhel_8/index#tc-ok_networking

So I think kubeadm is not impacted.

Comment: this command part of iproute rpm, tc command is missing on centos 8 `rpm -ql iproute |grep '/tc$'  `

Comment: Um...I think it seems tc package, but isn't this it?  
https://centos.pkgs.org/8/centos-baseos-x86_64/iproute-tc-4.18.0-11.el8.x86_64.rpm.html

Answer (score 7):

Please use to install:

```
dnf install -y iproute-tc
```

https://centos.pkgs.org/8/centos-baseos-x86_64/iproute-tc-4.18.0-15.el8.x86_64.rpm.html